# getting the Cisco Call Manager - Call data records (CDR) from .NET

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, interop, cisco

This question is an important research challenge for me!

Does anyone know any way to get the call detail records Cisco (CDR) from a net 3.5 application, which is not using the Web service CDROnDemand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure your Cisco Call Manager to push CDR to Radius server, install freeradius and collect cdrs and send to your .NET application.

Comment: new concepts to me. How can i push CDR to Radius server? thanks in advance

Comment: Was Esteban's follow-up ever answered? Is there a good web resource out there to read-up on? (other than freeradius' website - a little over my head)  Thanks for the help!